# Why the labels from tensorflow's shuffle do not work?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

every one!
From shuffle I got images and labels, images with conv works well.

images and labels from tfreocords

```
...
train_images, train_labels = shuffle(train_all_images, train_all_labels)
...
```

BUT `train_labels` does not work as below:

```
numpy.sum(numpy.argmax(predictions, 1) ==  train_labels)
```

The result is always wrong, because it cannot get values from `train_labels` at all.

Some details are below:

```
train_all_images, train_all_labels = read_and_decode("train")

train_images, train_labels = shuffle(train_all_images, train_all_labels)
```

......some training model

```
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate,
                                       0.9).minimize(loss,
                                                     global_step=batch)
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
    print('Initialized!')

    for step in xrange(int(num_epochs * train_size) // BATCH_SIZE):
        sess.run(optimizer)
        if step % EVAL_FREQUENCY == 0:              
            l, lr, predictions = sess.run([loss, learning_rate, train_prediction])

            print('Minibatch loss: %.3f, learning rate: %.6f' % (l, lr))
            print('Minibatch error: %.1f%%' % error_rate(predictions, train_labels))
            sys.stdout.flush()

def error_rate(predictions, labels):
    return 100.0 - ( 100.0 *
    numpy.sum(numpy.argmax(predictions, 1) == labels) /
    predictions.shape[0])
```

Comment: Can you include a complete reproducible example of the code that isn't working? From the two lines, it's not clear what's happening (e.g. what `sess.run()` call you're making, etc.).

Comment: hi,dude. I have modified my post again. would you please check it again? The key point is how to get the values of train_labels after shuffle? It is very confusing! Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you calling the `error_rate()` function? Is there an error message that could be helpful in finding the issue?

Comment: error_rate() just for calculating the prediction error rate

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have to use tensoflow mothods not numpy, below works well by accaray.

```
def correct_rate(out, labels):
  arg = tf.argmax(out, 1)
  arg = tf.cast(arg, tf.int32)
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(labels, arg)
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  return accuracy

accr = correct_rate(logits, train_labels)
print(sess.run(accr))
```